# How do we match the special character(s) in sybase using like?

Tags: sql, sybase

How do we match the special character(s) in sybase using like?

I'm using the like condition as a filter to any characters user inputted. Currently using the sybase database. I was able to retrieved some results by inputting some words, But if the user input some special characters like square bracket. It doesn't return any result but when I check the database I can see the square bracket or any special characters in the database.

```
Sample Data: column searchField : [IAN]Stackoverflow
Declare @value varchar(50)  
SET @value = '[IAN]Stackoverflow'  

SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE searchField LIKE '%@value%
```

Comment: Please provide your question with sample data.

Comment: That's not *sample data*. That's SQL. Post **sample data**, which is a sample of **data** like the values you're trying to `SELECT` from. (If you're not sure what the difference is between *data* and *SQL*, you might want to search for a tutorial.)

Comment: @KenWhite, The '[IAN]Stackoverflow' is the data I'm retriving...Did I miss something?.. I was offended

Comment: The part you mention is the value you're searching for. You were asked to provide the data you're **searching**. *Sample data*, not a sample search string. *I'm trying to find names like 'Smith'* defines a search term. *I'm trying to find it in a table that contains these values as data: *Simpson, Jones, Fredericks, Smithers, Simpson* provide the data.

Comment: @KenWhite, sometimes you have also to use your imaginations? since I already provided what I'm searching, probably that's the one I'm searching right? but the difference is I have the square brackets which is ignored.

Comment: Sorry. SO is not for *vaguely describe what you want and we'll use our imiagination to fill in the details* questions. You want help. You were asked to provide sample data so that we can help you. If you don't want to, either delete the question or be prepared to accept the downvotes you receive for not providing it or being willing to cooperate with people trying to give you free assistance to get an answer to your question. Your choice.

Comment: @KenWhite, I apologized.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking would be solved by:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE searchField LIKE '%' + @value + '%'
```

You can even have the variable part of the LIKE expression from a table, if you have more than one constant section in a list of values to compare:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Table1 t, #surnames s
WHERE t.searchField LIKE '%' + s.surname + '%'
```

or something like that.